# crossed second partial dervatives of $\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, and $f(0,0)=0$. An exercise asks to compute $\displaystyle\partial^2_{xy}f(0,0)=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y }(0,0)$ and $\displaystyle\partial^2_{yx}f(0,0)=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x }(0,0)$.

Here is my answer: one can check that $\displaystyle\partial_xf(x,y)=\frac{y^5-x^2y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, and is $0$ at $(0,0)$. One also has $\displaystyle\partial_yf(x,y)=\frac{3x^3y^2+xy^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, and $0$ at $(0,0)$.

For me $\displaystyle\partial^2_{xy}f(0,0)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\partial_yf(h,0)}{h}=0$ and $\displaystyle\partial^2_{yx}f(0,0)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\partial_xf(0,h)}{h}=1$.

But the answer says that both are equal to $0$.

**Can you confirm I am right?**

Comment: Why do you approach $(0,0)$ on the $x$ and $y$ axes only?

Comment: Because it is the definition of partial derivative: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Formal_definition
and because $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y }(0,0)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)(0,0)$

Comment: Oh yes, my bad.

Comment: The issue is that you evaluate the value early, so you lose some information before differentiating a second time. I'll write the details when I find the time.

Comment: Consequently you are wrong, which also confirms with Clairot's Theorem.

Comment: Spelling correction: it's "Clairaut".

Comment: I don't see the link with Clairaut's theorem.

Comment: Clairaut theorem says that if $f$ behaves well enough (in this case it does), then $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$.

Comment: Ok, I call it Schwarz relations. But it applies only if $f$ is $C^2$, and it is not the case here.

Comment: Yeah you're right, $f$ is $C^2$ everywhere except possibly at the origin, and your computations checks out with mine. For $(x,y)\neq0, f_{xy}=f_{yx}=\dfrac{3y^8+7x^2y^6+x^4y^4-3x^6y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^4}$, and for $x\neq0, f_{xy}(x,mx)=\dfrac{3m^8+7m^6+m^4-3m^2}{(1+m^2)^4}$, by which we can see that $f_{xy}$ is not continuous at the origin, so that there is no contradiction between the result and Clairaut's Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it appears the answer was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in polar-coordinates:

\begin{array}{l}
x = r\cos (\theta )\\
y = r\sin (\theta )
\end{array}

we have

$$g(r,\theta ) = f(r\cos (\theta ),r\sin (\theta )) = {r^2}\cos (\theta ){\sin ^3}(\theta )$$

and
$$\frac{{{\partial ^2}g}}{{\partial r\partial \theta }}(r,\theta ) = r(cos(2\theta ) - cos(4\theta ))$$

So, from this point of view, we get the right result.